# Running Python recursion on large numbers doesn't output or throws exception

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**8)

T = dict()

def downToZero(n):
    if n in T : return T[n]
    if n==1 : return 1
    T[n] = 1+downToZero(n-1)
    return T[n]

x = int(input())
print(downToZero(x))
```

Here is the code and it works for numbers like 100,1000 but when you input large numbers like 10,000, the console neither gives output nor it throws an error

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. For 10000, it finishes almost immediately for me. For 100000, it just segfaults.

Comment: Maybe you should wait a lil longer to see if your system ain't just being slow!  Your code simply return the exact input. I did with 10000 and got 10000 back. 100000 gave an output saying segment fault. I printed T and the assignments were successful

Comment: The title says "The python console" – which Python console is meant here? The standard ``python`` REPL? IPython? IDLE? Some other IDE?

Comment: Actually, when I run it in Jupyter notebook, for inputs like 1000 it runs perfectly, but as soon as my input reaches 10,000 I get a notification:'The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.'

Comment: So you do get an error message, namely that the kernel died?

Comment: When I was running my program on command prompt, I was actually getting no output, but after posting this question I also ran my output on Jupyter notebook and got this message

Answer (score 1):

You probably get something like:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
```

The error code `0xC00000FD` indicates StackOverflow.

Setting max recursion level with `setrecursionlimit` to `10**8` doesn't actually change the limit to that number; highest possible limit is platform-dependent (and smaller).